# How to properly configure Spring Validator (HibernateValidator)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm using Spring 4.2.7/Spring Boot 1.3.7 and I think the HibernateValidator is the default implementation that Spring uses in spring-web.

I would like to apply a configuration on the HibernateValidator like the following:

```
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class ).configure();

configuration.allowMultipleCascadedValidationOnReturnValues( true )
        .allowOverridingMethodAlterParameterConstraint( true )
        .allowParallelMethodsDefineParameterConstraints( true );
```

described in here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-method-validation-prerequisite-relaxation

I've tried defining a `@Bean` with something like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ValidatorFactory validatorFactory() {

    // ... the above snippet

    return configuration.getValidatorFactory()
}
```

But it looks the configuration is not applied.
I also tried defining the `Validator` bean like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public Validator validator(ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) {
    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
}
```

But the defined configuration does not seem to apply to the validator Spring is finally using.

- I am doing something wrong?
- Which should be the appropriate way to apply a configuration (configure/customize) like the one in the above example to the Spring Hibernate validator?

Answer (score 1):

Same question I want to know. I finally find this:

If you use Spring Boot as your application,
Spring Boot's *autoconfiguration* mechanism give us a Configuration class **ValidationAutoConfiguration**，in this class we can see the LocalValidatorFactoryBean Bean definition:

```
@Bean
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Validator.class)
public static LocalValidatorFactoryBean defaultValidator(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
        ObjectProvider<ValidationConfigurationCustomizer> customizers) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setConfigurationInitializer((configuration) -> customizers.orderedStream()
        .forEach((customizer) -> customizer.customize(configuration)));
    MessageInterpolatorFactory interpolatorFactory = new MessageInterpolatorFactory(applicationContext);
    factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(interpolatorFactory.getObject());
    return factoryBean;
}
```

So we can use the **ValidationConfigurationCustomizer** to config the HibernateValidatorConfiguration.